# OpenGL: Blinn-Phong model implemented in shaders give wrong result

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, lighting

First of all I'm new with computer graphics, openGL and have a basic knowledge of c++ coding. I have struggled with the openGL project like a month and have come to a point where I have to implement shading with Blinn-Phong model. I have implemented calculations in vertex and fragment shaders. There is/are propably some minor error(s) in code because without shading everything works perfectly but after shading parts are added to shaders anything does not happen. I calculate surface normals in fragment shader and also use textures instead of just colors. I also use for every objects (in total 7 objects) own shader.

I would be very happy if someone see right away where I'm doing wrong. I don't get errors anymore so propably the mistake is in implementation.

Here are the code for one objects vertex and fragment shaders.

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location=0) in vec3 in_Position;
layout (location=3) in vec2 in_TexCoord0;

// mvpmatrix is the result of multiplying the model, view, and projection matrices
uniform mat4 mvpmatrix;

// Texture coordinate for the fragment shader
out vec2 f_TexCoord0;
out vec3 out_Position;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = mvpmatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
    out_Position = in_Position;

    f_TexCoord0 = in_TexCoord0;
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 330 core
uniform sampler2D texture1;
in vec2 f_TexCoord0;
in vec3 out_Position;
layout (location=0) out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec4 ambientMaterial2, diffuseMaterial2, specularMaterial2;
uniform vec4 ambientLight, diffuseLight, specularLight;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform float shininess;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 ambientProduct = ambientLight * ambientMaterial2;
    vec4 diffuseProduct = diffuseLight * diffuseMaterial2;
    vec4 specularProduct = specularLight * specularMaterial2;

    vec3 pos = out_Position.xyz;
    vec3 nv = cross(dFdx(pos),dFdy(pos));
    nv = nv * sign(nv.z);
    vec3 L = normalize(lightPosition.xyz - nv);
    vec3 E = normalize(-nv); 
    vec3 H = normalize(L + E);
    vec3 N = nv;

    float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd * diffuseProduct;

    vec4 specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    if (Kd > 0.0f)
    {
        float Ks = dot(H, N);
        if (Ks > 0.0f)
            {
            specular = pow(Ks, shininess) * specularProduct;
            }
    }
    vec4 fragColor_lightning = (ambientProduct + diffuse + specular);
    vec4 fragColor_texture = texture2D(texture1, vec2(f_TexCoord0.x, f_TexCoord0.y));
    fragColor = fragColor_lightning + fragColor_texture;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Changed shaders:

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location=0) in vec3 in_Position;
layout (location=3) in vec2 in_TexCoord0;

// mvpmatrix is the result of multiplying the model, view, and projection matrices
uniform mat4 mvpmatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMat;

// Texture coordinate for the fragment shader
out vec2 f_TexCoord0;
out vec3 viewPos;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = mvpmatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
    viewPos = (modelMat * vec4(in_Position, 1.0)).xyz;
    f_TexCoord0 = in_TexCoord0;
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 330 core
uniform sampler2D texture1;
in vec2 f_TexCoord0;
in vec3 viewPos;
layout (location=0) out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec4 ambientMaterial2, diffuseMaterial2, specularMaterial2;
uniform vec4 ambientLight, diffuseLight, specularLight;
uniform mat4 viewMat;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform float shininess;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 ambientProduct = ambientLight * ambientMaterial2;
    vec4 diffuseProduct = diffuseLight * diffuseMaterial2;
    vec4 specularProduct = specularLight * specularMaterial2;

    vec3 pos = viewPos;
    vec3 nv = cross(dFdx(pos),dFdy(pos));
    nv = nv * sign(nv.z);
    vec3 L = normalize((viewMat*lightPosition).xyz - pos);
    vec3 E = normalize(-pos); 
    vec3 H = normalize(L + E);
    vec3 N = normalize(nv);

    float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd * diffuseProduct;

    vec4 specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    if (Kd > 0.0f)
    {
        float Ks = pow(max(dot(H, N),1.0),shininess);
        specular = Ks * specularProduct;
    }
    vec4 fragColor_lightning = (ambientProduct + diffuse + specular);
    vec4 fragColor_texture = texture2D(texture1, vec2(f_TexCoord0.x, f_TexCoord0.y));
    fragColor = fragColor_lightning + fragColor_texture;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to split the model view projection matrix to a model view matrix and a projection matrix. 
With the model view matrix the view position can be calculated and passed to the fragment shader.
With the projection matrix the clip space position can be calculated.

```
#version 330 core
layout (location=0) in vec3 in_Position;
layout (location=3) in vec2 in_TexCoord0;

uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 f_TexCoord0;
out vec3 viewPos;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 pos = modelview * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);;

    f_TexCoord0 = in_TexCoord0;
    viewPos     = pos.xyz;
    gl_Position = projection * pos;
}
```

For calculating a blinn phong light model see also [GLSL fixed function fragment program replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421778/glsl-fixed-function-fragment-program-replacement/45716107#45716107)

Change your code somehow like this:

```
in vec3 viewPos;

uniform vec4 lightPosition; // this has to be a view space position
uniform float shininess;

void main()
{
    ....

    vec3 N = cross(dFdx(viewPos.xyz),dFdy(viewPos.xyz));
    N = normalize(N * sign(N.z));

    vec3 L = normalize(lightPosition.xyz - viewPos.xyz);
    vec3 E = normalize(-viewPos.xyz); 
    vec3 H = normalize(L + E);

    float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd * diffuseProduct;

    vec4 specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    if (Kd > 0.0f)
    {
        float Ks = max(0.0, dot(H, N));
        specular = pow(Ks, shininess) * specularProduct;
    }

    .....
}
```

---

**Edit:**

When you do `viewPos = (modelMat * vec4(in_Position, 1.0)).xyz;` then `viewPos` is not a view position, but a model position. To calculate a view position you have to transform by the model matrix and the view matrix: `viewPos = (viewMat * modelMat * vec4(in_Position, 1.0)).xyz;`.

```
#version 330 core
layout (location=0) in vec3 in_Position;
layout (location=3) in vec2 in_TexCoord0;

// mvpmatrix is the result of multiplying the model, view, and projection matrices
uniform mat4 mvpmatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMat;
uniform mat4 modelMat;

// Texture coordinate for the fragment shader
out vec2 f_TexCoord0;
out vec3 viewPos;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = mvpmatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
    viewPos = (viewMat * modelMat * vec4(in_Position, 1.0)).xyz;
    f_TexCoord0 = in_TexCoord0;
}
```

---

Further I recommend to multiply the color of the texture by the light color:

```
fragColor = vec4(fragColor_lightning.rgb * fragColor_texture.rgb, fragColor_texture.a);
```