# OBJ file, after read mtl can not show the colors

Tags: opengl, 3d, light

I  used opengl to show the .obj 3D model. I found the model's color is wrong. Like this:
[From 3D Model Viewer software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9GMa.png)

[From my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SVeY.png)
This is my code:

```
void ObjLoader::renderObj()
{
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );

    for(int i=0; i<m_mtls.size();i++)
    {
        if(m_mtls[i]->hasTexture)
        {
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,m_mtls[i]->texture);
            glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            //glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            //glColor3fv(m_mtls[i]->Kd);
        }

        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, m_mtls[i]->Ka);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, m_mtls[i]->Kd);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, m_mtls[i]->Ks);
        glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, m_mtls[i]->Ns);

        glColor3fv(m_mtls[i]->Kd);

        glVertexPointer(3,GL_DOUBLE,0,m_mtls[i]->triVertexs);
        glNormalPointer(GL_DOUBLE,0,m_mtls[i]->triNormals);
        glTexCoordPointer(3,GL_DOUBLE,0,m_mtls[i]->triTextures);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,m_mtls[i]->triNum*3);

        glVertexPointer(3,GL_DOUBLE,0,m_mtls[i]->quadVertexs);
        glNormalPointer(GL_DOUBLE,0,m_mtls[i]->quadNormals);
        glTexCoordPointer(3,GL_DOUBLE,0,m_mtls[i]->quadTextures);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS,0,m_mtls[i]->quadNum*4);
    }

    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
}
```

I already analyse the mtl file. And you can see some face have the color. What is the problem? Do I need change the Light?

This is my Light code:

```
//set lights
GLfloat mat_specular[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
GLfloat mat_shiniess[] = {100.0};
GLfloat light_ambient [4] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
GLfloat light_diffuse [4] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
GLfloat light_specular[4] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
GLfloat light_position[4] = {1500.0,1500.0,1500.0,0.0};

GLfloat lmodel_ambient [] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};

//create light
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SPECULAR,mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SHININESS,mat_shiniess);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR,light_specular);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,light_position);
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT,lmodel_ambient); 
glLightModeli( GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE );
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values for the light are to high. Note in the standard light model the ambient, diffuse and specular part of the light are summed.

The standard OpenGL [Blinn-Phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model) light model is calcualted like this:

```
Ka ... ambient material
Kd ... difusse material
Ks ... specular material

La ... ambient light
Ld ... diffuse light
Ls ... specular light
sh ... shininess

N  ... norlmal vector 
L  ... light vector (from the vertex postion to the light) 
V  ... view vector (from the vertex psotion to the eye)

Id    = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);

H     = normalize(V + L);
NdotH = max(dot(N, H), 0.0);
Is    = (sh + 2.0) * pow(NdotH, sh) / (2.0 * 3.14159265);

fs    = Ka*La + Id*Kd*Ld + Is*Ks*Ls;
```

Since all your light values are initialized by `{1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0}`, this gives a sum which is greater than 1.0 in most cases and the rendered objects is almost white.

I recommend to use a small ambient light part, because it is added to the entire object independent of the incident light.

```
GLfloat light_ambient[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
```

Use a strong lambertian diffuse light component, which reflects the direction of the light well.
See [How does this faking the light work on aerotwist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061745/how-does-this-faking-the-light-work-on-aerotwist/45121641#45121641)

```
GLfloat light_diffuse[] = {0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f};
```

With the specular light component you have to experiment. Its effect depends strongly on the shininess parameter.

```
GLfloat mat_shiniess[]   = {20.0f};
GLfloat light_specular[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
```