# opengl light reduce reflection

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting, opengl-compat

I am trying to apply a light in my scene.
However all objects are reflecting extremely and the colors get distorted.

[image]

How can I get a reflection similar to this example:

[image]

I assume I am choosing the wrong values for the materials?

This is how I setup light and materials:

```
void createLight() {

    GLfloat mat_specular[] = {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 1.0 };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    // Lighting set up
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    // Set lighting intensity and color
    GLfloat qaAmbientLight[]    = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
    GLfloat qaDiffuseLight[]    = {0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0};
    GLfloat qaSpecularLight[]   = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, qaDiffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, qaSpecularLight);

    // Set the light position
    GLfloat qaLightPosition[]   = {12, 8, 12, 0.4};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, qaLightPosition);

}
```

Comment: Ah yeah this did the job, nice !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values for the light are to high. Note in the standard light model the ambient, diffuse and specular part of the light are summed.

The standard OpenGL [Blinn-Phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model) light model is calcualted like this:

```
Ka ... ambient material
Kd ... difusse material
Ks ... specular material

La ... ambient light
Ld ... diffuse light
Ls ... specular light
sh ... shininess

N  ... norlmal vector 
L  ... light vector (from the vertex postion to the light) 
V  ... view vector (from the vertex psotion to the eye)

Id    = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);

H     = normalize(V + L);
NdotH = max(dot(N, H), 0.0);
Is    = (sh + 2.0) * pow(NdotH, sh) / (2.0 * 3.14159265);

fs    = Ka*La + Id*Kd*Ld + Is*Ks*Ls;
```

Since your specular light values are initialized by `{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};`, this may give a sum which is greater than 1.0 in the cases where the normal vector of the object points to the light. This causes that the rendered objects looks almost white.

I recommend to use a small ambient light part, because it is added to the entire object independent of the incident light.

Use a strong lambertian diffuse light component, which reflects the direction of the light well.
See [How does this faking the light work on aerotwist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061745/how-does-this-faking-the-light-work-on-aerotwist/45121641#45121641)

With the specular light component you have to experiment. Its effect depends strongly on the shininess parameter. But start by using a small value for the specular light and a shininess of about 10.0.

```
GLfloat mat_shininess[]   = {10.0};
GLfloat qaAmbientLight[]  = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
GLfloat qaDiffuseLight[]  = {0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0};
GLfloat qaSpecularLight[] = {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0};
```