# opengl-es pre pixel lighting issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader, lighting

there is a problem that i just can't seem to get a handle on..
i have a fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform vec3 u_AmbientColor;
uniform vec3 u_LightPos;
uniform float u_Attenuation_Constant;
uniform float u_Attenuation_Linear;
uniform float u_Attenuation_Quadradic;
uniform vec3 u_LightColor;

varying vec3 v_Normal;
varying vec3 v_fragPos;

vec4 fix(vec3 v);

void main() {

    vec3 color = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);

    vec3 vectorToLight = u_LightPos - v_fragPos;
    float distance = length(vectorToLight);
    vec3 direction = vectorToLight / distance;
    float attenuation = 1.0/(u_Attenuation_Constant + 
    u_Attenuation_Linear * distance + u_Attenuation_Quadradic * distance * distance);
    vec3 diffuse = u_LightColor * attenuation * max(normalize(v_Normal) * direction,0.0);
    vec3 d = u_AmbientColor + diffuse;
    gl_FragColor = fix(color * d);
}
vec4 fix(vec3 v){
    float r = min(1.0,max(0.0,v.r));
    float g = min(1.0,max(0.0,v.g));
    float b = min(1.0,max(0.0,v.b));
    return vec4(r,g,b,1.0);
}
```

i've been following some tutorial i found on the web,
anyways, the ambientColor and lightColor uniforms are (0.2,0.2,0.2), and (1.0,1.0,1.0)
respectively. the v_Normal is calculated at the vertex shader using the
inverted transposed matrix of the model-view matrix.

the v_fragPos is the model result of multiplying the position with the normal model-view matrix.

now, i expect that when i move the light position closer to the cube i render, it will just appear brighter, but the resulting image is very different:

[image]

(the little square there is an indicator for the light position)
now, i just don't understand how this can happen?
i mean, i multiply the color components each by the SAME value..
so, how is it that it seems to vary so??

EDIT: i noticed that if i move the camera in front of the cube, the light is just shades of blue.. which is the same problem but maybe it's a clue i don't know..

Comment: it changed the cube appearance for a far from bluish to yellowish.. but same when coming closer...

Comment: yeah i got that.. just mentioned that it had a different result for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Lambertian reflectance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance) is computed with the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the normal vector and the vector to the light source, instead of the component wise product.
See [How does the calculation of the light model work in a shader program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061745/how-does-the-calculation-of-the-light-model-work-in-a-shader-program/45121641#45121641)

Use the [`dot`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/dot.xhtml) function instead of the `*` (multiplication) operator:

<s>`vec3 diffuse = u_LightColor * attenuation * max(normalize(v_Normal) * direction,0.0);`</s>

```c
vec3 diffuse = u_LightColor * attenuation * max(dot(normalize(v_Normal), direction), 0.0);
```

---

You can simplify the code in the `fix` function. `min` and `max` can be substituted with `clamp`. This functions work component wise, so they do not have to be called separately for each component:

```c
vec4 fix(vec3 v)
{
    return vec4(clamp(v, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0);
}
```

Comment: yes now it looks good :) i'm still not sure as to why the different colors though..

Comment: well, you saved me yesterday also :) i know it's a noob's mistake.. and i really do appreciate your help! i was staring at the code for literally hours :) many thanks!