# Why is direction vector facing the opposite way?

Tags: glsl

I'm currently learning lighting in OpenGL and was reading learnopengl.com when I noticed that they calculated the direction of the light (diffuse lighting) by subtracting the light position to the fragment position:
`vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);`
(I've attached an image to show what this would look like)
[Direction Vector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXpNP.jpg)

Why would they get a vector that points from the Fragment position to the light position? If they want to get the light direction, wouldn't we want to get a vector from the light position to the fragment position:
`vec3 lightDir = normalize(FragPos - lightPos);`

Comment: The diffuse light is calculated by the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the normal vector and the vector form the surface to the light source. See [How does the calculation of the light model work in a shader program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061745/how-does-the-calculation-of-the-light-model-work-in-a-shader-program/45121641#45121641)

Answer (score 0):

The diffuse light is calculated by the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the normal vector and the vector form the surface to the light source. See [How does the calculation of the light model work in a shader program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061745/how-does-the-calculation-of-the-light-model-work-in-a-shader-program/45121641#45121641)